# Django multiupload error: 'list' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: django, forms, multi-upload

I'm trying to use multiupload in django form for upload several images at once.
I'm using django `ModelForm` but when i'm calling `form.is_valid()` in function-base view or using `generic.FormView`, i'm getting `'list' object has no attribute 'name'` error. in `generic.FormView` neither of `form_valid` and `form_invalid` methods aren't called. although when I use `request.POST.get(some_data)` it works without any errors but I want to use `generic.FormView` for some validations. I think the validation of the form makes the error happen.
so what should I do?
here is my code.

`models.py`

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="posts")
    text = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    ...

class Image(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="images")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/posts/")
```

`forms.py`

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    images = MultiImageField(min_num=1, max_num=3)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Post
        fields = ("text", "images")
```

`views.py`

```
class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.FormView):
    template_name = "posts/post_create.html"
    form_class = forms.PostForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return redirect("profile", slug=self.request.kwargs.slug)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        ...
        # some codes
        ...
        return super(CreatePostView, self).form_valid(form)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py", line 73, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 119, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 152, in post
    if form.is_valid():
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 205, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 200, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 433, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 443, in _clean_fields
    value = field.clean(value, bf.initial)
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\forms\fields.py", line 670, in clean
    return super().clean(data)
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\forms\fields.py", line 200, in clean
    self.run_validators(value)
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\forms\fields.py", line 185, in run_validators
    v(value)
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\validators.py", line 611, in validate_image_file_extension
    return FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=get_available_image_extensions())(
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\validators.py", line 576, in __call__
    extension = Path(value.name).suffix[1:].lower()

Exception Type: AttributeError at /profile/ehsanadmin/post/create/
Exception Value: 'list' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: please add the error code also, somewhere in your code you are calling ```ListObject.name```.

Comment: @shivankgtm error code added.

Comment: please have a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files)